# transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL with jta-data-source

Tags: jpa, db2, websphere-liberty, openjpa, open-liberty

I came across an old project using OpenJPA with DB2 running on Websphere Liberty 18. In the persistence.xml file there is a persistent unit with the following declaration:

```
<persistence-unit name="my-pu" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">       
<provider>org.apache.openjpa.persistence.PersistenceProviderImpl</provider>
<jta-data-source>jdbc/my-data-source</jta-data-source>
</persistence-unit>
```

In the case that we are using **RESOURCE_LOCAL** transactions and there is code to manually manage the transactions scattered throughout the whole application, shouldn't the data source be declared as "non-jta-data-source"? Interestingly it seems the application is working fine despite that. Any ideas why it works fine?

Comment: Why shouldn't it work? `jta-data-source` is supposed to point at a **JTA-aware** data source, and if you use it, transaction type is set to JTA by default, but since you've explicitly asked to use `RESOURCE_LOCAL` transactions instead, nothing special happens

Answer (score 1):

`<non-jta-data-source>` specifies a data source that refuses to enlist in JTA transactions.  This means, if you do userTransaction.begin (or take advantage of any API by which the container starts a transaction for you), and you perform some operations on the data source (which is marked with transactional="false" in Liberty) those operations will not be part of the encompassing JTA transaction and can be committed or rolled back independently.  It's definitely an advanced pattern, and if you don't know what you are doing, or temporarily forget that the data source doesn't enlist, you can end up writing code that corrupts your data.  At this point, you may be wondering why JPA even has such an option.  I expect it isn't intended for the end user's usage of JPA programming model at all, but is really for the JPA persistence provider (Hibernate/EclipseLink/OpenJPA) implementation.  For example, if you consider the scenario where a JTA transaction is active on the thread and you perform an operation via JPA where the JPA persistence provider needs to generate a unique key for you, and the persistence provider needs to run some database command to reserve the next block of unique keys, the JPA persistence provider can't just do that within your transaction because you might end up rolling it back, and then the same block of unique keys could be given out twice and errors would occur. The JPA persistence provider really needs to suspend your transaction, run its own transaction, and then resume yours. In my opinion suspend/resume would have been the natural solution here, but the JTA spec doesn't provide a standard way to obtain the TransactionManager, and so my guess is that the JPA spec invented its own solution for situations like this of requiring a data source that bypasses transaction enlistment as an alternative. A JPA provider can run its own transactional operations on the non-jta-data-source while your JTA transaction continues on unimpacted by it.  You'll also notice with the example I chose, that it doesn't apply to a number of paths through JPA. If your JPA entity is configured to have the database generate the unique keys instead, then the persistence provider doesn't need to perform its own database operations on a non-jta-data-source. If you aren't using JTA transactions, then the persistence provider doesn't need to worry about enlisting in your transaction because it can just use a different connection, so it doesn't need a non-jta-data-source there either.